# How to fix Electron App not rendering on some Windows Server Machines?

Tags: windows, electron

I installed my Electron Windows App on a fresh Windows 10, Windows Server 2016 Standard and Windows Server 2012 R2 Build 9600 and it is working fine. The connection to my websocket is also working.

On some machines with Windows Server 2016 Standard the app is not working as expected. I am just getting the windows border of the app but no content nor a menu. But the websocket connection of my app is working. ( i checked it with wireshark). so i guess it is a rendering problem?

Sadly i don't have access to the machines where the problem exists.
I assume same packages are missing?

screenshot with rendering problem:
[image]

Electron 5.0.2
Electron Store 3.2.0
Electron Prompt 1.3.1

Comment: do you know if .net is installed on those servers?

Comment: i got the info that .net framework 3.5 and .net framework  4.6  is installed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue as you mentioned, I solved it by generating a 32bit version of my Electron app for that Windows Server it did not work on.

Here is my build snippet from my package.json to generate both a 64 and a 32 bit version.

```
    "build": {
    "appId": "com.example.app",
    "productName": "app",
    "copyright": "Copyright © 2019",
    "files": [
      "build/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*"
    ],
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "assets"
    },
    "win": {
      "target": [
        {
          "target": "portable",
          "arch": [
            "x64",
            "ia32"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "icon": "assets/app.ico"
    }
   },
```

Comment: Did this solve your problem? For me, if I include both arch's still on win server 2019 the x64 is executed which does not work. If I just include ia32, the app works on Win server 2019